# Pyspark appending junk characters like 'F4FFFF' in binary data while saving it into blob storage

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, binary

I have a dataframe with one row which contains binary data and I am uploading it into blob storage.
Before uploading the length is same as it is expected.
After uploading spark is adding extra characters in the beginning, ending and in between of the data.

[Characters appended in the end⁹

[Characters appended after every 65500 bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qag0n.jpg)

Please help.I have tried every options there is when uploading from pyspark. Nothing is working so far

Comment: How are you uploading this file to the blob storage. Paste the line of code that writes data to the blob storage

Comment: The code looks like this
Df.write.repartition(1).mode("ignore").save(path_location).     df has only one row which is in binary format and has hex data in it. While saving the output starts with "par1" and ends with some metadata about the dataframe along  with this"par1". And they are added as hex and when we decode it we can see its the mentioned keyword